# Why is the sum of array incorrect?

Tags: arrays, assembly, sum, mips

First number in the array (5) gives the size of the array. the remaining numbers are the elements in the array.

Expected answer is 10
Actual answer is 11

Very new to this so I'm not sure why its giving me the wrong answer.

Code:

```
.data
array: 
.word 5 
.word 0, 1, 2, 3, 4

.text
.globl main
main:

la $t2, array
add $t0, $0, 1 # i = 1
lw  $t4, 0($t2) # $t4 = 5 array[0] = 5
add $t1, $zero, $zero   # sum
addi $t5, $t4, 1  # $t5 = 6

loop:

slt $t3, $t0, $t5 # i > 6?
beq $t3, $zero, done

lw  $t4, ($t2)  # $t4 = array[i]
addi    $t2, $t2, 4

add $t1, $t1, $t4 
addi    $t0, $t0, 1 # i++
j loop
done:

add $a0, $0, $t1     

li  $v0, 1
syscall

li  $v0, 10
syscall
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Well, 5+0+1+2+3 = 11. Use the simulator's debugging features to inspect the runtime behavior of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code:

```
lw  $t4, 0($t2)
```

Code above: T2 is the array. The lw gets the 1st array value and puts into t4, which is ok.

```
addi $t5, $t4, 1  # $t5 = 6
```

Code above: Is setting your array limit the arraysize + 1, which is ok.

```
lw  $t4, ($t2)  # $t4 = array[i]
```

Code above is getting array[i], HOWEVER that isn't what you wanted - you wanted array[i+1] (ie: don't include array[0])

Perhaps easiest is to increment t2 to the array[1] and then do the loop:

```
  addi $t2, $t2, 4 # set address to &array[1]
loop:
```